# correct open meta graphs when sharing url to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi i have this site and i want that when i shared the url link in facebook the logo and description for the site will goes out. And when i shared the blog url to facebook also gets the information in the blogs when shared in facebook. sample blog url is http://www.testing.com.au/blog/this-is-it Now what happened is i have this meta tags added in my html code so when i shared the url in my facebook the logo and description is correct. Now when i shared the blog url in my facebook the logo and description will goes out which is now wrong. Here is my meta tag code below:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/400dpiLogo.png" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Testing website" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="testing website is very nice." />
```

Now this code works well especially when sharing the url to facebook 
http://www.testing.com.au
i tried using facebook object debugger to know if it works well
here is my other code as well:

```
<!-- Open Graph Meta Tags BEGIN -->
        <meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
            <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:pageName.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
            <meta expr:content='data:pageName.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
        </b:if>
        <meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:title'/>
        <meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
            <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
        </b:if>
        <!-- Open Graph Meta Tags END -->
```

But its not working well. I keep searching in google but have no luck.
Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

just check your URL with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ 
it says clearly which tags are missing or incorrect